# rvest: how can I visualize the html session webpage in Rstudio?

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
library(rvest)
s <- html_session("http://had.co.nz")
s %>% jump_to("thesis/")
s %>% follow_link("vita")
```

Now I want to make sure I have navigated to the right webpage, how can I visualize the webpage in Rstudio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I provide two ways because I didn't get which one you are interested in:

```
library(rvest)
s <- html_session("http://had.co.nz")
t <- s %>% jump_to("thesis/")
v <- s %>% follow_link("vita")
```

For any of the above `t` or `v` you can use the following to view the html code and see if it is correct:

```
html(t$url)
html(v$url)
```

OR after @Mohammad's very useful comment:

```
#if you are on windows
shell.exec(t$url)
shell.exec(v$url)

#if you are on mac
system(paste("open", t$url))
system(paste("open", v$url))
```

Or a cross-platform option as per @MrFLick's comment:

```
browseURL(t$url)
browseURL(v$url)
```

To actually view the webpage itself.

(I don't think you can use Rstudio's viewer for non-local web content, if this is what you are asking).

Comment: Thanks @LyzandeR . If Rstudio does not view a non-local web content, how can I make sure that Im in the right webpage?

Comment: You are welcome! It has to be one of the other two ways I provided. You either print out the `html` code (first piece of code) which includes the web page's text or you just view the webpage itself on a browser by using the second piece of code (which is a programmatic way to do it).

Comment: Thanks again @LyzandeR. I just figured out shell.exec doesn't work in mac. The equivalent function for mac is: system(paste("open", t$url))

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning this! It is very useful for people with the same problem. I have added this to my answer.

Comment: `browseURL()` might be a better (safer/cross-platform) choice for opening the file in the browser

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the comment; I have added in my answer. I didn't know of this function. It is indeed better and safer.